# Re-Display MOTD in Linux/Deblin system that's already logged in

Tags: linux, debian, motd

I am looking to re-display the MOFD in a Linux/Deblin  system that is already logged in.

I have already edited the etc\motd file and this does display my custom motd output in the terminal when I ssh in to my Linux/Deblin system. However, what I want ot do is to Re-display the motd when I clear the terminal.

for example, after I logged in via ssh and the motd is displayed I will then inupt the commands that I wish to run then i will enter the "clear" command to clear the terminal, what I want to do is redisplay the motd after I have cleared the terminal.

the only way I know to redisplay the motd is to log out of the terminal then log back in.

Is there a command to redisplay the motd without logging out and back in to the terminal? (via ssh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cat /run/motd.dynamic
```

or possibly this:

```
cat /var/run/motd.dynamic
```